# Display a QPixmap or QImage in ImageView in pyqtgraph

Tags: pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm looking to display an array of RGBA in an ImageView. The only way I am currently able to do so is to make a QImage then a QPixmap and displaying it in a label. However I want it to be displayed in an ImageView to give it all of the other features that I have already implemented. Is this possible?

```
qimage = pg.fn.makeQImage(x)

pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)

imvOCTTopLeft.close()

elasticity = QtGui.QLabel()

layout.addWidget(elasticity,4,1)

elasticity.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ImageView.setImage(img)](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/imageview.html) the argument has to be a 3d numpy array with shape (width, height, 4). The last dimension is rgba in the range 0 to 1.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = pg.mkQApp()
    w = pg.ImageView()
    image = np.array([np.array([np.array([1, i*0.01, i*j*0.0001, 1]) for i in range(100)]) for j in range(100)])
    w.setImage(image)
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

This library will help you convert between QImage and ndarray
https://github.com/hmeine/qimage2ndarray/